# Non-linear system of 4 unknowns

Tags: polynomials, problem-solving, nonlinear-system

What are the non-zero solutions in $x,y,z$ and $t$ of the following system of equations
\begin{cases} 
(1+ax+bz)(1-x)=1\\ 
(1+cy+bt)(1-y)=1 \\ 
(1+dx+bt)(1-z)=1\\
(1+fy+bz)(1-t)=1
\end{cases}

Comment: The solution is several pages long. Do you have concrete values for $$a,b,c,d,f$$?